# Regex Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to do Regex from a website url, but it gets me an error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

```
Regex re = new Regex("\"id\":\"([0 - 9] +)\"");
string ree = re.Matches(sr)[0].Value;
MessageBox.Show(ree);
```

The url output is just blank page with text. http://prntscr.com/a6xyi0

Comment: `[0 - 9] +` -> `[0-9]+`

Comment: Thank you! But how could I make it get all ID's there's not just one

Answer (score 1):

You have to move all the spaces you don't want match, you can use [0-9]+ or \d+

You can iterate over all matches for every id in the string:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\"id\":\"(?<id>\\d+)\"");

string[] ree = re.Matches(sr).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
// Or if you just want the id:
string[] ree = re.Matches(sr).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["id"].Value).ToArray();

foreach (var item in ree)
{
    //do something
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want add the results to a `ListView` then this should work for you:

```
var sr = "{\"id\":\"11111\", ...} {\"id\":\"22222\", ...} {\"id\":\"33333\", ...} {\"id\":\"44444\", ...}";
Regex re = new Regex("\"id\":\"(?<id>\\d+)\"");
var ree = re.Matches(sr).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["id"].Value);

foreach (var item in ree)
{
    var lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { item, "who column" });
    listView.Items.Add(lvItem);
}
```

And you will get some like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again! Last question http://prntscr.com/a6yh33

Comment: @TõnisKivimägi: seems like trading is a ListViewItem and you just are changing the text before add it, you have to create a new one: var trading = new ListViewItem(ree);

Comment: Everytime? or just once?

Comment: each time in the loop

Comment: Why I can't just add to one listviewitem, because I am "exporting" that listviewitem to listview as well.

Comment: if you only want to change the text then you do not have to add it, but if you want to add many items, then you have to create a new one, this is a restriction of ListView and ListView, this is how it was designed.

Comment: Can you help me out with code how I could make it to get "ALL" those ID's from that page and put it to listviewitem and from there add to listview(Got some parts of code)

Comment: I edited my answer to add the code.

Comment: Thank You! Now I get each number into each column: http://prntscr.com/a6z2am

Comment: @TõnisKivimägi: If my answer helps you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I meant, how could I fix it getting id into one columns, not ID each number it it's own columns

Comment: I edited the answer, but I not sure if this is what you want

Comment: Hmm, Cannot convert char to string & I'll explain better.

Comment: ID is like 858385 example, but it if it adds to ID it only adds "one" number t o each column
So it should be like
Columns: ID
                858385
At the moment it is like
Columns: ID
                8
                5
etc etc...

Comment: In the image you added, ListViewItem is not showed, can you added it. but problably this is because you are converting the string to char[].

Comment: I am not converting it, thinking how you are able to use it like that, but I can't :D

Comment: columns are added using the designer?

Comment: if so then you just need something like this: var lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "column1", "column2", "colum3" });

Comment: Yeah, I added columns through designer

Comment: using this should work greats: var lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { "value of id column", "value of who column", "etc", "etc"  });

Comment: There's many "other" id's as well, but now it only takes just that one and adds it.

Comment: You try with the code in my answer? you will gets a result like the image.

Comment: Almost, I have only some things different. Hmm, idk how I should get other id's because it's just now putting one id over and over again :/

Comment: Sorry, i don't get what you means